# Is it possible to get different equation numbers when utilizing different label prefixes?

Tags: labels

I am writing a document in latex and I utilize \begin{equation} to write mathematical expressions, but also to draw some circuits (Quantum Computing stuff). For the circuits I utilize a specific label prefix circuit:somelabel, while for the mathematical equation I am using the standard eq:somelabel prefix.

Is it possible to generate separate numbers for separate prefixes? For example, I want the first equation in the second section to be labeled (2.1) while for the first circuit I want [2.1], for example. Now I get (2.1) for both when referencing.

Comment: Many people will tell you that you should post a Minimal Working Exampe (aka `MWE`) showing what you tried and what is wrong.

Comment: General speaking, prefix of label name is too late to alter the style of equation tag. You might use different environments and different counter to typesetting equations and quantum computing staff.

Comment: Are you using \eqref or cleverref?